# JavaScript concurrency in updating arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, firefox

This is probably a vary noob question, but I cannot figure out what is happening. I have a simple function that I run:

```
function f() {
  var x = [{a:1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}];
  console.log(x);
  x.push({a: 5, b: 6});
  console.log(x);
f();
```

The two console.log outputs show the same thing with all three elements which I cannot understand. If I change function so that the array only contains numbers:

```
function f() {
  var x = [1, 2];
  console.log(x);
  x.push(3);
  console.log(x);
f();
```

then the outputs looks as I would have expected with the first one showing a list with items 1,2 and the second showing a list with 1,2,3.

This all runs in Firefox.

Comment: It's because the reference to the array is only expanded when you click on it on the console. If you use JSON.stringify, you will see its current state.

Should be marked as a dupe but I couldn't find it

Comment: I think this is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: `console.log` is a type of I/O, and hence asynchronous. https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch1.md#async-console plus the linked answers above have more in-depth explanation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays It is not related to the console being sync/async, it's just that the object is lazily evaluated when you expand it